# Argument of type click.File, but closing the file early?

Tags: python, click

The `click.File()` type is useful for handling `-` as stdin, as well as automatically closing the file safely upon command exit.

However, if my program might run for a long time, I don't want to leave this file open for that whole time. Is there some official recommended technique to close the file early if I know I'm done with it? I don't see a `close` method or equivalent anywhere in the [API docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.File).

I do see a `close` method [on the internal `_AtomicFile` class](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/6986b08a7e4107e23f81ec7101d862e7116bc574/src/click/_compat.py#L454-L470) but it's not clear to me if that's considered part of the public interface, or if it's safe to call that function in user code.

I tried this, and it seems to work as expected, but I have no idea if it's considered safe or valid:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("-f", type=click.File())
def cli(f):
    data = f.read()
    data.close()
    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```